# Which javascript package provides a rich object model for drawing different shapes on the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript

What is the best javascript package for drawing different shapes (circle, rectangle, ball, table, ...) on the HTML5 Canvas

Comment: What do you mean by "table" - like an HTML `<table>`, or a [dining table](http://www.google.com/images?q=dining+table), or...?

Comment: I was referring to a html table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to drawing things like balls, tables etc. you probably want to just use clip art. Then to tie it all together (lines, ellipses, etc. etc. and images) you could use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org) with its [`image()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/image_) function, or do it directly in JavaScript (a bit more difficult but not hard).

Comment: Why does everyone always down-vote advice type answers? Besides, http://processingjs.org was a good suggestion.

Comment: And additionally to that, if you want to draw the shape without images, Processing.js is good for doing that as well.

Answer (score 3):

I recently found a nice javascript library called [Joint](http://www.jointjs.com). It is a JS library for drawing diagrams on a SVG/VML canvas. It is build on top of the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) library, which you should definitely check out if you want a nice basic set of drawing tools. Althouhg they are not drawing to the HTML canvas, they are definitely worth checking out, if you need to draw something with javascript.

Comment: +1 joint seems cool. @sam I also highly recommend raphael if you don't need the bitmap stuff that canvas has to offer.

Answer (score 2):

[Gury](http://guryjs.org/) is a simple canvas wrapper with a "fluent interface" (think jQuery).

While it doesn't really have drawing primitives *per se* (at least not yet), it should be fairly simple to create your own and be able to reuse them.

Follow [this link](http://thechangelog.com/post/1291711468/gury-a-jquery-inspired-html5-canvas-javascript) to see the page where I learned of it. There's a very small intro and some sample code there.

If you're interested the [source file for the demos on Gury's homepage](http://guryjs.org/javascripts/demos.js) also shows how you draw several stuff, including boxes, balls and even slider widgets. Just search for the different `draw` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to draw 3D shapes **[three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js)** looks pretty promising. It's still in active development and the demos are really the only documentation at the moment but looks to be pretty functional as it stands now.